# Why does index = -1 when the elements exist in the array?

Tags: java, arrays, indexing, selection-sort

```
public void swap(int a, int b) {                                                                                                                                                                                          
    int indexA = Arrays.asList(nums).indexOf(a);
    int indexB = Arrays.asList(nums).indexOf(b);

    nums[indexA] = b;
    nums[indexB] = a;
}
public void selectionSort() {
    int x = 0;
    findIndexOfMinAfter(0);
    swap(nums[x], nums[x + 1]);
}
```

`int[] nums` is an array I passed in. When I called the swap method, both `a` and `b` exist in the array but `indexA` and `indexB` return `-1`. Any idea why it does that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Arrays.asList` is a generic method that takes an array of objects. In this case, the entire `int` array is considered as an object because its elements are of the primitive type `int`. As a result,  `Arrays.asList` is returning a list of arrays instead of a list of integers.

You can solve this by turning `nums` into an array of `Integers`:

```
Integer[] nums;  // instead of int[]
```